# Varnish stops responding after saving Turpentine config on Magento

Tags: magento, varnish

So I'm getting a blank page and Varnish stops responding after saving turpentine config.

Turpentine Varnish Server List is correct (127.0.0.1:6082). 
I've no other cache extension, all caches are disabled but Varnish Pages and Varnish ESI Blocks.

I can access the website through port 8080 (Apache) and 80 (Varnish) before saving the turpentine config, after clicking save I can only access it on port 8080. If I restart Varnish everything start working again, then if I refresh the Turpentine config page magento displays that the Turpentine config was saved successfully, but there is no difference on speed and Varnish Hits stays at 0.

Details:

- CentOS 7
- Varnish 4.0.3
- Magento 1.7.0.2
- Turpentine Release 0.6.7

On /etc/varnish/varnish.params:

```
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
DAEMON_OPTS="-p cli_buffer=16384 -p vcc_allow_inline_c=on"
```

On /etc/varnish/default.vcl:

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
```

default.vcl downloaded from magento:
https://gist.github.com/hmvar/48b637bc8f52090140fb#file-default-vcl

Comment: What version of Turpentine are you running?

Answer (score 0):

When you deactivate the Varnish ESI Blocks Cache in the Cache Management, did you get an answer from your site?

Maybe it could be the missing parameter `-p feature=+esi_ignore_other_elements` in the `varnish.params` for the DAEMON_OPTS settings.

Comment: I'm not able to test it now, as soon as I test it I'll post the results, appreciate the help